# How to use sgi stl in g++

Tags: c++, stl, g++, sgi

I want to debug SGI STL in g++ (version 4.1.2)
I downloaded source code in http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/download.html and put them in a directory,such as /stl
and then g++ -I/stl m.cpp
but it causes a lot of complie errs,why?

m.cpp

```
#include "list" //I want to include **/STL** not **/usr/include/c++/...**
using namespace std
int main()
{return 0;}
```

Thanks

I just want to debug SGI STL in g++,what should I do?Is this feasible???

Comment: "SGI STL" -- why? "version 4.1.2" -- why?

Comment: Compiling 14 year old source code with a 7 year old compiler may involve hurdles beyond just setting the include paths..

Comment: I think the source code is more readable than others,and I have been using fedora8

Comment: ["f8 final release ... november 2007"](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/8/Schedule)

Answer (score 1):

[Gcc looks](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) here (subject to your exact setup)

> GCC looks in several different places for headers. On a normal Unix system, if you do not instruct it otherwise, it will look for headers requested with #include  in:

```
 /usr/local/include
 libdir/gcc/target/version/include
 /usr/target/include
 /usr/include
```

But you can change that easily with `g++ -nostdinc -I/stl m.cpp`.

The compiler errors are likely cause by the different built in code, but we can't tell without seeing them.

Comment: STL will call c++ standard library,so can't use -nostdinc.

Comment: What is the point of an stl (aka c++ standard library) that calls another? perhaps you mean it calls c standard library, in which case you will need to -I/path/to/c/headers which is described in the link (in fact my post shows the list but is missing the c++ header pat, whoops)